# Mini210 can not play any video

Tags: embedded, arm, windows-ce, bsp

I have the [Mini210](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini210) board, I Installed both WINCE6 & Android on it.

I can not play any video, Like MP4 ,264 or AVI on it.

it does not recognize any of this formats.

I looked at It's BSP on wince, it only have two drivers. and does not have any driver for MFC( multi format video codec).

any Idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In WinCE it is I believe your responsibility to select the [required video format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee483919%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx) support in [Platform Builder](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jk5DInQKVpc)